# Create fulltext index within Entity Framework Coded Migrations

Tags: entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations, full-text-indexing

**TLDR; How do you add a full text index using Entity framework 5 coded migrations**

I'm having issues adding a full text index to a database using Entity framework migrations. It needs to be there from the start so I'm attempting modifying the InitialCreate migration that was automatically generated to add it.

As there isn't a way to do it via the DbMigrations API I've resorted to running inline sql at the end of the 'Up' code.

```
Sql("create fulltext catalog AppNameCatalog;");
Sql("create fulltext index on Document (Data type column Extension) key index [PK_dbo.Document] on AppNameCatalog;");
```

When this runs everything gets created fine until it reaches this sql, then it throws the the sql error '*CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG statement cannot be used inside a user transaction.*'. Which is expected and working as designed.

Thankfully Sql() has an overload that allows you to run the sql outside the migration transaction. Awesome! I thought.

```
Sql("create fulltext catalog AppNameCatalog;", true);
Sql("create fulltext index on Document (Data type column Extension) key index [PK_dbo.Document] on AppNameCatalog;", true);
```

But low and behold modifying the code to do this (see above) results in a new timeout error '*Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.*'

I've tried spitting out the sql and running it manually and it works fine. I've also diff'd the generated sql with and without running it outside a transaction and they are identical so it must be something in the way sql is executed.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a similar problem. My InitialCreate migration was creating a table and then attempting to add a full text index to that table, using the overloaded Sql() to indicate that it needs to execute outside the transaction. I was also getting a timeout error and I suspect it's due to a thread deadlock.

I could get it to work in some scenarios by using Sql() calls instead of CreateTable() and by merging the CREATE FULL TEXT CATALOG and CREATE FULL TEXT INDEX statements into a single Sql() call. However, this wasn't very reliable. Sometimes it would work and sometimes it would fail with the same timeout error.

The only reliable solution I found was to move the creation of the catalog and full text index into a separate migration.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the input. Did it work as a separate migration then?

Comment: Yip, I've got it working as a separate migration. Table creation happens in the InitialCreate migration and the Full Text Catalog and Indexes are created in a separate migration that is intended to be performed after the InitialCreate migration.