# Is there a way to automate adding the FullText Index to an Entity Framework migration

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, full-text-search

Yes [I can add the script to the Migration.Up()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16546326/create-fulltext-index-within-entity-framework-coded-migrations) everytime I revise my model. But that is fundamentally no different from having a CreateIndexes.sql that I just run in SSMS after creating a DB.

Is there some way to declare the full text indexes in fluent or somewhere so they are automatically incorporated into the migration?